# How can I add libCurl to a Borland C++ Builder 6 Project?

Tags: c++builder, libcurl

How can I add libCurl to a Borland C++ Builder 6 Project? I tried including its directory in the project's compiler and linker search paths, then I made a lib from the libcurl dll and I added it to the project, I'm trying to get a piece of sample code to compile, but it throws on error that it doesn't find `curl/curl.h` in the line `#include <curl/curl.h>`. The libCurl installation did not come with a visible`curl/curl.h` file, and I'm not a mainly C++ programmer, so I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the curl-7.19.7 zip and found curl/curl.h in the include directory there. So you’ll have to add curl-7.19.7\include to your include paths for it to see curl/curl.h